# Will cloudflare cache files that are hidden behind my sign_in process in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, cloudflare

I've built an app based on the Hartl course, where users sign_in and out of the app. Unless there's a current_user defined, the sessions controller sends any page request to the login page and asks that person to sign_in.

I've now added Cloudflare as a convenient way to serve the static assets and provide an SSL solution whilst I Beta test my app, but I was wondering whether it is caching anything behind the sign_in process? i.e. if I visit my site now and sign_in, then view a page that is hidden to all other visitors (because they don't know my username/password), is this html cached by Cloudflare too?

If it is, how do I stop Cloudflare from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Cloudflare (Cloudflare's CDN, to be precise) doesn't cache HTML pages, only CSS and JS. Actually, you just can't cache dynamic HTML pages on CDN, because one URL can return different HTML pages, and after caching dynamic HTML you'll end up in the situation when one user receives a profile of another user.

But you can enable caching of static HTML pages by using Cloudflare's Page Rules feature.

Comment: Thanks Jeiwan, I appreciate this. As you can tell I'm new to using both together, and just wanted to ensure I'd added security with the SSL/Cloudflare rather than compromised it.